# Creating syntactic sugar for a scala argument to give the illusion of a different type

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-reflect

I am creating a library and am exposing a class called A that has in it defined a function `func(f: SomeType => A)`. It is **imperative** that func is called with the following syntax:

```
val x = new A()
val y = new A()
x.func(_ => y)
```

However in reality I want the body of `func()` to perform logic based on the **value** of y. The function being passed as argument is not actually important.

I'm new to Scala and I have looked into using implicits and scala reflect with little joy. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Can `SomeType` be any generic type?

Comment: @DanGetz Yes the type of SomeType isn't important as it's being disregarded in the body of `func()` anyway.

Comment: Could you give a more specific example with real values and use cases?

Comment: @B-Brennan "not important" is not the same thing as generic: is it necessary that the library user can choose a different type for `SomeType`? Or can you the library writer choose whatever is most convenient for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a much better question than the one from the other day :)

Let's discuss the type of `_ => y`. If your contract is such that the user must provide a function, and in reality they should provide one which totally ignores the argument and produces `y`, then you should probably make it `Unit => A`. That way, `func` body can just apply the received function to an empty value.

Let's say that `A = Int`:

```
val f: Unit => Int = _ =>  42

def func(f: Unit => Int) = {
  f() // apply f to empty argument
}

func(f) // 42
```

The only point of creating such a thunk would be to achieve lazy evaluation of `y`. Similar effect can be achieved by taking the call-by-name parameter (indicated by `=> Type`) instead of a function:

```
def func(f: => Int) = {
  f
}

func(42) // 42
```

If you can't change the function type from `SomeType => A`, then you can obtain `y` by providing any kind of `SomeType`. Even `null`.

Let's say that `SomeType = String` and `A = Int`:

```
val f: String => Int = _ =>  42

def func(f: String => Int) = {
  f(null) // ugly but works
}

func(f) // 42
```

But keep in mind that this is extremely weird and misleading. If the function is not important, why is it being required? Someone could provide the following `String => Int` function:

```
val f: String => Int = _.length
```

And what you're saying is, "I don't care about the input String". Well, how are you going to obtain the `Int` then? If you decide to obtain the `Int` by passing some `String` value to `f`, which value are you going to pass?

You would have to rely on the user of your library to always provide a function that doesn't care about the input argument, such as `val f: String => Int = _ => 42` (as shown in an earlier example). Then you can obtain your `Int` by providing whatever random dummy `String` value, or even null, "knowing" (= hoping) that the provided function will ignore its argument.